# How to secure REST API PUT/POST calls being called manually through postman

Tags: rest, api, security, postman

Actually I have an API called update user data, it is called when the user moves from one page to another page. If the user copy the API from console and post in postman, user should not able to update the user data. How to provide security or implement feature to not to update data through post man.

Comment: Include authentication and authorization facilities in your API.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't.

You can slightly make it harder using some CSRF protection, but that's just it - it will only make it a bit harder, but not stop anyone determined.

If your API is public, you should be ready for your users to have custom client apps.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by your question. Because PostMan or other applications like Fiddler are created to make the job easier for developers during development. anyhow if you are concern about who makes call to your webpage, you can make your API private and just give access to the user that have the right credentials. You can also read about **CSRF** or **XSS**.